# How to add styles to jest snapshot while testing vue component?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I had tried to use Jest for snapshot testing for Vue SFC. And I missed styles inside the generated snapshot file, only class names. Is it possible to add style rules to snapshot?

```html
<template>
  <div class="woof"></div>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue-class-component';

  export default class Component extends Vue {};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  .woof {
    background-color: red; // <- this part is missing inside snapshot file
  }
</style>
```

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Component from './Component.vue';

describe('Component testing', () => {
  it('looks as expected', () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Component);

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Comment: Why would the styles be in the snapshot? They aren't part of the virtual DOM.

Comment: @jonrsharpe because these styles are part of the component and can be covered by tests. Look at the `jest-styled-components` and you can see it very convenient to use.